Global SQLAlchemy session in Quart
In Flask-SQLAlchemy, the global db.session object is bound to the application context and is unique to each request. This is convenient to support atomic transactions within the web request - if anything fails, everything rolls back in a final commit for the route.
It's unclear how to create something similar (preferably without extensions) in Quart. It seems like I could bind a new session to g before request and close it after request. I would prefer an independent proxy variable I could import (e.g. from app.database import session).
Documentation for Quart-db suggests best practice is a new session for each small task. I don't see how that can ensure an atomic web request that involves database IO across various files (e.g. model methods, helper functions, support code) all used within a route.
What is the best way to implement a safe session that starts and ends with the request?
